# Virtualmin Remote.api remove alias

Tags: dns, alias, webmin

How can I delete only domain alias using Virtualmin Remote.api?

I tried with:

```
virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=delete-domain&domain=domain_alias_name&user=username
```

but it deleted the whole domain not only the alias.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the user option. When I removed it it deleted only the alias.